# Is it possible to record who opens a file in Google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I recently just switched over to the Google platform and I was wondering if it is possible to write a Google script that will record the email address of everyone who opens a specific file I have created in our Google drive. Ideally I would be able to get all of the emails in a Google sheet.

Comment: Yes,If you have their explicit permission,i.e.,They should all install the script in the same file. No sneaking behind their back :)

Comment: Yes they will be aware. The thought behind it is to know if a specific person has read a report I published since the last update. This way I know if I need to email them that changes were made. If that makes sense.

Comment: It's better to email them  all than asking them all to install a script.

Comment: Consider Drive API - you can access the `File#viewedByMe` and `File#viewByMeTime` properties: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files

Comment: Again I am very new to this. My first thought was to just put a script in the workbook. I'll will look into the API options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below ended up working for me. This takes a sheet and whenever it is opened by someone it records their Email address and the date in a separate google sheet in Google Drive.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1u8QluCjBTjkuy-kyzHNbyi6er8dr-8IUlEZt9cBuPg0").getSheetByName("logSheet");
  s.getRange(s.getLastRow()+1,1,1,2).setValues([[ email,new Date()]]);
}
```

Again this is only accessible for people directly in my department at work and the actual user does not matter. We just need to see if the files are being used. I instead am using google analytics to track the usage of the files. I find it makes more sense to look at usage with analytics.